# Will Conditional formatting to hide a column in a SharePoint list work if the column name contains a /?

Tags: list, formatting

I have a choice column name that is "this/that" with the choices "this" and "That". I would only like some other columns in the list to appear when "this" is selected. However I keep getting an error message when I am formatting the columns. Is it because of the / in the column name? here is the formula:

```
=if([$this/that] == 'this', true, false)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the internal name of the column, which would be `this_x002f_that`. That would make the full formula `=if([$this_x002f_that] == 'this', true, false)`

You can find the internal name for a column by going into the column settings and looking at the end of the URL.

[image: Column settings]

Comment: Columns in SharePoint have two names, an internal name and a display name. The internal name is set when the column is created and it never changes. The display name can be changed at any time.

When column names have special characters in them, those special characters get encoded. In the case of your column, the slash character would have been encoded as `_x002f_`.

Comment: that worked. Thanks so much!